Supplying a reason for AbortController?
This code aborts the request after 10 ms:
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;


fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
        signal
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log('Data:', data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        if (err.name === 'AbortError')....

    });

 
setTimeout(() => {
    controller.abort();
 
}, 10);

Output :

DOMException: signal is aborted without reason

Question:
If it says "without a reason," is it possible to supply a reason?
Because otherwise, the message is a bit strange, as if I could supply a reason but didn't.

controller.abort("some reason"); as per "documentation"

You can supply a reason as an argument to controller.abort(), like controller.abort("took longer than 10 milliseconds")
From MDN:

abort()
abort(reason)


reason (optional): The reason why the operation was aborted, which can be any JavaScript value. If not specified, the reason is set to "AbortError" DOMException.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort
